# USA record keeping requirements when hiring overseas freelancers

Tags: taxes, payments

Does anyone know what the payment receipt requirements are for a USA client hiring freelancers from other countries?  I know I don't need to do a 1099 for them as a foreign freelancer would not need pay US Income taxes.  But are there any records I need so I can deduct the payment from my income, beyond a PayPal or  credit card receipt that shows I paid them?

I have hired people through sites like eLance and oDesk knowing those sites handle the record keeping for me, but I have someone I'd like to hire directly and I want to make sure the IRS can't come back and deny my deduction of the money I pay him.

Thanks - and I hope this question is appropriate for this forum.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have not done this, but it seems to me that a record of your payment (through a CC transaction or bank record) should be sufficient.

It will depend on how you are filing - if this is a corporate tax return or a schedule C for your company, you would **not** put the amount under wages paid to others, you would put the payment in the line item associated with that kind of expenditure, as if you were purchasing a product from another company. This person is a vendor (or consultant) and you are paying their business entity.

Answer (score 1):

From what I've been doing there are no real requirements/laws. You should just document all the payments you make for tax purposes and keep copies of any agreements you have with them.  They are independent contractors.